# реализация системы "гостей" php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

здравствуйте, хочу реализовать систему "гостей пользователя", думаю понятно о чем идет речь

я знаю как это все сделать но вот один вопрос у меня есть. чтобы не выводить одного и того же гостя по несколько раз, а выводить только последних 10ти уникальных гостей, то "фильтрацию" нужно сделать до внесения в бд или на моменте вывода?

допустим таблица будет простой, поле userid и guestid, как лучше всего сделать так чтобы не было повторов? спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в таблицу поле `last_visit` (например). Когда пользователь будет заходить на страницу, проверяйте, заходил ли он раньше и просто обновляйте `last_visit`.

При выводе 10 последних уникальных гостей сортируйте по `last_visit`.

Другой вариант – при выборе из таблицы группировать по guestid (`SELECT ... GROUP BY guestid`)